# MVC3: Get the value of controls added via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, textbox, controller

I added a textbox to my form via javascript as follows

```
<input type="text" name="odd" id="odd" />
```

and I added a parameter in my model

```
public string odd {get; set;}
```

Now, I wish to retrieve the text in this textbox in the controller by calling the variable odd, but it is always empty. Is there something I need to do to bind these two together besides giving them the same name?

EDIT

My form looks like

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerName", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { enctype ="multipart/form-data" })){
  <div> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.model1.mode,
                        new SelectList(Model.model1.mylist, "Value", "Text"), "Select", new { @onchange="javascriptFxn(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);"})
                    <div id="Other"></div>
 }
```

and the javascript looks like

```
javascriptFxn(name){
  document.getElementById('Other').innerHTML = '<br /> <input type="text" name="odd">';
 }
```

my Model 1 looks like

```
public class model1{
  public string odd {get; set;}
 }
```

and the submit for controller

```
  public ActionResult Submit(MyModel model)
   {
      string s = model.model1.odd;
   }
```

Comment: If the input name and the model property name are matching it should work. Can you extend your question with more context? How do you submit your form? How do your model and controller action look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the portions of the code provided, it looks like your Model (being passed to view) does not have Odd property, instead the the model has a Model1 property that in turn has Odd property. Try having Odd property directly on your model and check if the value is posted when the form is submitted.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks very much. But will is it so? Why can't I define it in model1?

Comment: well, when a form is submitted the form variables are directly mapped to the object the controller is expecting(in this case MyModel).. when ASP.NET MVC does not find a property called Odd on MyModel, it ignores it.